# Actix web actors are being created more than once

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-actix

I am just playing a bit with Actix web and Actix actors, while I was building a simple app which gives out milliseconds I observed that Actix is creating more than one actor. I want to restrict it to only one, but I am unable to do it.

What's the wrong thing I have done here. I cannot build Actor `Addr` outside closure and use in routes as it gives compilation error. But if I move the creation of actor within closure, depending on number of workers it gets created more than once.

What I wanted to achieve is, irrespective of the number of workers I need to use only one actor.

**main.rs**

```rust
mod millis_provider;

use actix::*;
use actix_web::{App, get, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, web};

use crate::millis_provider::Millis;
use crate::millis_provider::MillisProvider;



struct MillisConsumer {
    millis_provider: Addr<MillisProvider>
}

impl MillisConsumer {
    fn new(millis_provider: Addr<MillisProvider>) -> Self {
        MillisConsumer { millis_provider }
    }


    async fn millis(&self) -> std::result::Result<u128, std::io::Error> {
        self.millis_provider.send(Millis {}).await.expect("Failed to get result from actor")
    }
}

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Use /millis GET request to obtain unique millis")
}

#[get("/millis")]
async fn millis(millis_consumer: web::Data<MillisConsumer>) -> impl Responder {
    let millis = &millis_consumer.millis().await.unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(millis.to_string())
}

use structopt::StructOpt;
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;


#[derive(StructOpt)]
struct GeneratorConfig {
    http_host: String,
    http_port: i32,
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let config = GeneratorConfig::from_args();
    SimpleLogger::new().init().unwrap();

    // let actor: Addr<MillisProvider> =
    //     MillisProvider {
    //         current_millis: 0,
    //         total_millis_generated: 0,
    //     }.start();

    HttpServer::new(move || {

        let actor: Addr<MillisProvider> =
            MillisProvider {
                current_millis: 0,
                total_millis_generated: 0,
            }.start();

        App::new()
            .data(MillisConsumer::new(actor))
            .service(millis)
            .service(hello)

    })
       // .workers(1)
        .bind(format!("{}:{}", config.http_host, config.http_port))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

**millis_provider**

```rust
use log::{info};

use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

use actix::{Actor, Handler, Message, Context};

#[derive(Message)]
#[rtype(result = "std::io::Result<u128>")]
pub(crate) struct Millis;

pub(crate) struct MillisProvider {
    pub(crate) current_millis: u128,
    pub(crate) total_millis_generated: u128,
}

fn get_epoch_ms() -> u128 {
    SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
        .map(|x| x.as_millis())
        .expect("Failed to get time in millis")
}

impl Actor for MillisProvider {
    type Context = Context<Self>;

    fn started(&mut self, _: &mut Self::Context) {
        info!("Actor started");
    }

    fn stopped(&mut self, _: &mut Self::Context) {
        info!("Actor is stopped");
    }
}

impl Handler<Millis> for MillisProvider {
    type Result = std::io::Result<u128>;

    fn handle(&mut self, _: Millis, _: &mut Context<Self>) -> Self::Result {
        let mut current_time = get_epoch_ms();
        while current_time == self.current_millis {
            current_time = get_epoch_ms()
        }
        self.current_millis = current_time;
        self.total_millis_generated += 1;
        if self.total_millis_generated % 1000 == 0 {
            info!("Generated total of {} ids", self.total_millis_generated);
        }
        Ok(self.current_millis)
    }
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust-actix-example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["mtekp <manjunath@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"


[dependencies]
log = "0.4"
structopt = "0.3.13"
actix = "0.10"
actix-web = "3"
simple_logger = "1.11"
```

**logs**

```
2021-03-03 20:43:12,090 INFO  [actix_server::builder] Starting 4 workers
2021-03-03 20:43:12,091 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,091 INFO  [actix_server::builder] Starting "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" service on 127.0.0.1:8080
2021-03-03 20:43:12,091 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,091 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 INFO  [rust_actix_example::millis_provider] Actor started
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 INFO  [rust_actix_example::millis_provider] Actor started
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [actix_server::worker] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 INFO  [rust_actix_example::millis_provider] Actor started
2021-03-03 20:43:12,093 TRACE [actix_server::worker] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
2021-03-03 20:43:12,093 TRACE [actix_server::worker] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,092 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,093 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,093 INFO  [rust_actix_example::millis_provider] Actor started
2021-03-03 20:43:12,093 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,094 TRACE [mio::poll] registering with poller
2021-03-03 20:43:12,094 TRACE [actix_server::worker] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
```

We can see `Actor started` 4 times here based on number of workers.
Ran with `cargo run -- 127.0.0.1 8080`

Answer (score 1):

The change which worked is, deriving `Clone` for `MillisConsumer` and cloning it inside closure worked.

**New main.rs**

```rust
mod millis_provider;

use actix::*;
use actix_web::{App, get, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, web};

use crate::millis_provider::Millis;
use crate::millis_provider::MillisProvider;


#[derive(Clone)]
struct MillisConsumer {
    millis_provider: Addr<MillisProvider>
}

impl MillisConsumer {
    fn new(millis_provider: Addr<MillisProvider>) -> Self {
        MillisConsumer { millis_provider }
    }


    async fn millis(&self) -> std::result::Result<u128, std::io::Error> {
        self.millis_provider.send(Millis {}).await.expect("Failed to get result from actor")
    }
}

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Use /millis GET request to obtain unique millis")
}

#[get("/millis")]
async fn millis(millis_consumer: web::Data<MillisConsumer>) -> impl Responder {
    let millis = &millis_consumer.millis().await.unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(millis.to_string())
}

use structopt::StructOpt;
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;


#[derive(StructOpt)]
struct GeneratorConfig {
    http_host: String,
    http_port: i32,
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let config = GeneratorConfig::from_args();
    SimpleLogger::new().init().unwrap();

    let actor: Addr<MillisProvider> =
        MillisProvider {
            current_millis: 0,
            total_millis_generated: 0,
        }.start();

    let consumer = MillisConsumer::new(actor);
    HttpServer::new(move || {

        let c = consumer.clone();
        App::new()
            .data(c)
            .service(millis)
            .service(hello)

    })

        .bind(format!("{}:{}", config.http_host, config.http_port))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```